# How to colour background using the contents of another cell

Tags: excel

Is it possible to change the colour of a cell using the contents of another cell?

Im trying to create a paint conversion table, converting colours of paint from one brand ID to another brand ID. I have included in my chart the six digit RGB number so I would like to create a cell next to it that shows the colour, so that at a glance you can see roughly the colour you are looking at

So for example

```
Cell A1 = FFFFFF then Cell B1 would be coloured White
Cell A2 = 000000 then cell B2 would be black
Cell A3 = 8E999D then cell B3 would be a light grey
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks
Penny

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of color palette, it will be better if you use RGB format. Check the below code and hope this is what you want:

```
Sub try()

If Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
Range("B1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If

If Range("A2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
Range("B2").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If

End Sub
```

And so on you can continue with other cells as well.

Comment: OK, at risk of sounding stupid, what do I do with that code. I tried to enter it into the actual cell and it came up #error and I couldnt find anywhere to insert that into the conditional formatting.
That looks like a special programming language to me

Comment: @PenelopeBlake: You can use Conditional Formatting or Use my above code. You cannot enter this code into cell. This is VBA programming, we have VBE editor for this inbuilt into excel. You can do googling for this and reasearch on the same.

Comment: I dont know how to insert images but here is what ive done

The Basic sheet is a colour conversion chart for my own reference

Cell A1 is a basic FS code
Cell B1 is the code in RGB e.g. FFFFFF
Cell C1 is a code for the type of paint (eg matt, gloss etc)
Cell D1 is a the combination of B1 and C1 to make a code for my own reference, so a glossy white would become 255-255-255-G
The cell E1 is the one I want coloured. It should fill it in with a colour match for B1.

Its not designed to be an exact colour chart, but should sho you the rough differences in the colours.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This sounds promising, how I would I do it with conditional formatting?

Comment: OK, Im sure Ive done something wrong here
Ive put your code into VBA thingy, then in the cell Ive entered =getRGB1({cell}) and every time it comes up as FFFFFF

So, apparantly, all of the following RGB codes are white

4A5D2C
9B9D9F
9B9D9F
9B9D9F
9B9D9F
EA723D
CD4F3A
CD4F3A
FFFFFF
E8E7E0
333221
A09F9F
AB8957
C0C7C5
C9CACC
8E999D
DDE3E0
625F34
9B9D9F

???????